# Wordpress: How to exclude thumbnails by attachment id

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I'm using a [Sweet Cake](http://themeforest.net/item/sweet-cake-responsive-wordpress-theme/5514731) theme from themeforest. As you can see on **Works** are shown all projects. I want to rename "Show all" and exclude some of the items by their attachment ids. How can I exclude them? Here is the code:

```
<?php

$args=array(
    'type'                     => 'attachment',
    'child_of'                 => 0,
    'orderby'                  => 'name',
    'order'                    => 'DESC',
    'hide_empty'               => 0,
    'hierarchical'             => 1,
    'post_status'              => 'inherit',
    'taxonomy'                 => 'portfolio',
);

$categories=get_categories($args);


 foreach($categories as $category) { ?>
    <li><a style="background-color:<?php echo $category->description; ?>;" href="#filter" data-option-value=".<?php echo $category->slug; ?>"><?php echo $category->name ?></a></li>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your args array, add the 'exclude' option:

```
'exclude' => array(3, 5, 6), // IDs of the categories you wish to exclude
```